# alternate or good way of inherting the class output

Tags: c#

as you guys can see from the code i created three classes car,new model,main . all the basic methods are in car class , i created the inherited class to try (inheritance). as you can see what i am doing is just output the wheel() method of car class with newrims() method of newmodel inherited class to make a complete sentence.need suggestion to make the code more accurate.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
   public class car
   {
    public static void wheel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The wheels are rolling");
    }
    public static void doors()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Doors are automatic");
    }
    public static void engine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The engine of car is runing");
    }
    public static void oil()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the oil is full in tank");
    }
   }
   public class newmodel : car
   { 
    public static void newrims()
    {
        car.wheel();
        Console.WriteLine("And The new rims are rocking");
    }

  }

  class Program
  {
      static void Main()
      {
         while (true)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Press A to Roll the Wheels baby");
            Console.WriteLine("Press B to Open/Close the Doors");
            Console.WriteLine("Press C to Start the Car Engine");
            Console.WriteLine("Press D to Check the Oil in tank");
            Console.WriteLine("Press E to Rims/wheels");
            Console.WriteLine("Press F to Exit the vehicle");
            char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'a':
                    {
                        car.wheel();
                        break;
                    }
                case 'b':
                    {
                        car.doors();
                        break;
                    }
                case 'c':
                    {
                        car.engine();
                        break;
                    }
                case 'd':
                    {
                        car.oil();
                        break;
                    }
                case 'e':
                    {
                        newmodel.newrims();
                        break;
                    }
                case 'f':
                    {
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Correct Input");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `base`, not `car`.

Comment: I am struggling to understand your actual question...

Comment: also is this your homework? please try to add tag correspondingly

Comment: @Mudu question updated. @ sundar nop thats not my homework :)

Comment: You're getting an error message here, correct? You could add that error message to your question to get better help.

Comment: @CodeCaster could you add that as an answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of inheritance in your case would be something like this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class car
    {
        //note the absence of static keyword..it means it is an instance method
        //note the virtual keyword..it means derived classes can override the behavior
        public virtual void wheel()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The wheels of car are rolling");
        }

    }

    public class newmodel : car
    {
        //note the override keyword....it means newmodel overrides the wheel function
        public override void wheel()
        {
            //depending on your needs you may or maynot 
            // need to call the base class function first
            base.wheel();
            Console.WriteLine("And The new rims are rocking");
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Instead of static methods you create a car object on
            //on which you invoke member functions
            car currentcar = new car();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press A to Roll the Wheels baby");
                Console.WriteLine("Press N to switch to new model");
                char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (c)
                {
                    case 'a':
                        {
                            currentcar.wheel();
                            break;
                        }
                    case 'n':
                        {
                            currentcar = new newmodel();
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Correct Input");
                            break;
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you will notice that pressing `a` will call the wheel function but depending on whether your car is the plain old car or the new model it will print different things to the Console.

Comment: I think he wants the output from the `car.wheel()` function as well.

Comment: That's probably what the OP is looking for. Might want to emphasize the actual change regarding base.wheel(). in the original question the `newmodel` didn't have a `wheel()` function, but a `newrims()` function. That would make it even easier, since it would suffice with a `wheel();`.

Comment: @Default I added some inline comments

Comment: @parapurarajkumar thanks really helpful for a beginner like me :)

Comment: wonderful :) looks good to me

Comment: looks awesome thanks for the comments in the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the statics ... create a Car and/or NewModel instance from the classes and use the instances.

I don't have actual references, however some things to take into account:

- if you use static on most functions, probably you made a design flaw.
- you already made a base class and inherited class which is good
- instead of using static functions, create a car object (i.e. currentCar = new Car()  and create also a newModel instance)
- use the functions on those instances instead of the class, then you can remove the static keywords.
- when using one single variable (i.e. currentVehicle, which you can create from a car: i.e. currentVehicle = new car(), you can later change it into a new model and use the new model's functions, like currentVehicle = new newmodel()
- Normally classes are written with capitals, so Car and NewModel, and variables/instances of classes without capitals: i.e. car = Car(), newModel = NewModel()

Comment: thanks i am beginner can you give me some good ref

Comment: I added a lot of comments in my answer above.

Comment: you are welcome (please upvote the answer in that case so others might benefit too from it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly because you're using a switch statement to determine which methods to call and you're not really using inheritance or polymorphism the way it was intended. But, let me show you an example below of how you might structure this differently.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4 
{ 
   public abstract class car 
   { 
    public virtual void wheel() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("The wheels are rolling"); 
    } 
    public virtual void doors() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("The Doors are automatic"); 
    } 
    public virtual void engine() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("The engine of car is runing"); 
    } 
    public virtual void oil() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("the oil is full in tank"); 
    } 
   } 

   public class standardmodel : car
   {
   }

   public class newmodel : car 
   {  
    public override void wheel() 
    { 
        base.wheel();
        Console.WriteLine("And The new rims are rocking"); 
    } 

  } 

  class Program 
  { 
      static void Main() 
      { 
         while (true) 
         { 
            Console.WriteLine("Press A to Roll the Wheels baby"); 
            Console.WriteLine("Press B to Open/Close the Doors"); 
            Console.WriteLine("Press C to Start the Car Engine"); 
            Console.WriteLine("Press D to Check the Oil in tank"); 
            Console.WriteLine("Press E to Rims/wheels"); 
            Console.WriteLine("Press F to Exit the vehicle"); 
            char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); 

            Car standard = new standardcar(),
                newModel = new newmodel();

            switch (c) 
            { 
                case 'a': 
                    { 
                        standard.wheel(); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                case 'b': 
                    { 
                        standard.doors(); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                case 'c': 
                    { 
                        standard.engine(); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                case 'd': 
                    { 
                        standard.oil(); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                case 'e': 
                    { 
                        newModel.wheel(); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                case 'f': 
                    { 
                        Environment.Exit(0); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                default: 
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Correct Input"); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

But again, this isn't really a very good example overall because it's not clear what you're trying to do. Something you could add to the above code to make it more OO like is to use a factory to determine which type of `car` to create and then you would just have a car. I hope this answers your question.